# NameError when splitting app and views code

Tags: python, flask

I want to divide my code into two parts, the app initialization and the view definitions.  I import my views and define my app, but I get `NameError: name 'manager' is not defined`.  Why am I getting this error?  How do I split up my code correctly?

`manage.py`:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask.ext.script import Manager

import viewports

manager = Flask(__name__)

if __name__=='__main__':
     manager.run()
```

`viewports.py`

```
@manager.route('/')
def Home():
     return render_template('Home.html', title='FrontPage')
```

Comment: `from manage import manger`. You might want to [read some documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/).

Comment: @HenryGomersall this will cause another import error for there is no module named manager...

Comment: @HenryGomersall Oops ... My fault, I wrote it into manager instead of manage... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a circular import: first you import `viewports`, which imports `manager`, which is only defined after you import `viewports`.  You also didn't organize your code correctly, everything should be under one package.  You also confused creating a Flask-Script manager with creating a Flask app.  Also, `flask.ext` is deprecated, import directly from the package name.

```
my_project/
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    manage.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)

from my_app import views
```

`views.py`:

```
from my_app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

`manage.py`:

```
from my_app import manager

manager.run()
```